# What is SQL Server's equivalent to MySQL's OPTIMIZE command?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, equivalent

Is there an equivalent of MySQL's [OPTIMIZE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html) command for SQL Server?

Comment: I don't know mysql and didn't feel like researching this for very long but it sounds incredibly similar to reorganizing and rebuilding indexes. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858.aspx

Comment: There's the ability to defrag indexes but I don't think there's a synonymous command due to the fact table data is stored according to how it's clustered index is configured and page data is shuffled on insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends:

1. If current table has a clustered index then `ALTER INDEX ALL ON [Schema].[Table] REBUILD` is one solution.

> If ALL is specified and the underlying table is a heap, the rebuild
>   operation has no effect on the table. Any nonclustered indexes
>   associated with the table are rebuilt.

([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx))

So, for heap tables this statement will not rebuild also the heap structure. Regarding this solution, please see all warnings from [All](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx) section (Specifying ALL with this operation    Fails if the table has one or more).

but

2. If current table is heap (it doesn't have a clustered index) then I would use `ALTER TABLE [Schema].[Table] REBUILD`
   In this last case, for heap tables this statement rebuilds heap structure but also all non-clustered indexes ([source](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2009/08/28/heaps-forwarding-pointers-alter-table-rebuild-and-non-clustered-indexes.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

In T-SQL you can rebuild and reorganise indexes like this:

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON [dbo].[SomeTable] REBUILD
```

You might also want to check out this MSDN article on specifying an index fill factor.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177459.aspx